# python multiple processing with multiple arguments with for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am having trouble with the multiple processing model.
when passing a single argument with a for loop, my code works:

```
def job(a):
    pass

p = Pool()
res = [p.apply_async(job, (a,)) for a in A]
p.close()
p.join()
```

When passing multiple arguments with a for loop, I couldn't get it to work. Is this possible?

```
def job(a, b, c, d):
    pass

p = Pool()
res = [p.apply_async(job, (a,), (b, c, d) for a in A]  #??
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Why are you still passing the single argument?

Comment: in your case, i guess you should pass a single tuple, like this  `[p.apply_async(job, ((a,), (b, c, d)) ) for a in A]` be carefull with parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a syntax. 
Try this:

```
 res = [p.apply_async(job,(a,b,c,d)) for a in A]
```

Comment: this works out as well. Thanks. I thought I tried this. There must be something I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

how abut using a `multiprocessing.Pool`? 
It will iterate through your input and by using `partial` you can pass more arguments to it.
like this:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial


def job(a, b, c):
    print("{} - {} - {}".format(a, b, c))

def main():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
    func = partial(job, "static arg1", "static arg2")
    pool.map(func, iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the output will be:

```
static arg1 - static arg2 - 1
static arg1 - static arg2 - 2
static arg1 - static arg2 - 3
static arg1 - static arg2 - 4
static arg1 - static arg2 - 5
static arg1 - static arg2 - 6
```